# What should be the default launcher icon size

Tags: android

I refer to the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#icon-sets

Hence, I plan to have the following directory structures.

```
res/
    drawable/   
        icon.png (? x ? px)
    drawable-ldpi/  
        icon.png (36x36 px)
    drawable-mdpi/  
        icon.png (48x48 px)
    drawable-hdpi/  
        icon.png (72x72 px)
```

However, I cannot find any documentation, to mention the size of default launcher icon size.

May I know what should be the default launcher icon size?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need to supply an image in the `drawable/` directory if you have populated `drawable-ldpi/` `drawable-mdpi/` and `drawable-hdpi/` with launcher icons.

Comment: Any document reference on your statement?

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK I've not seen a document that states it explicitly, but all the docs I've read either talk about populating `drawable/` *or* `drawable-ldpi/`, `drawable-mdpi/` and `drawable-hdpi/`, not both.  In my own app I don't have the base `drawable/` directory and have not found any issues with launcher icon scaling on various devices.

Comment: Plain "drawable" resources are necessary for Android 1.5, API 3 devices.  The drawable-DENSITYdpi directories were introduced with Android 1.6.

Answer (score 15):

Android icon sizes

```
ldpi : 36x36px (120 dpi / 47 dpcm)
mdpi : 48x48px (160 dpi / 62 dpcm)
hdpi : 72x72px (240 dpi / 94 dpcm)
xhdpi : 96x96px (320 dpi / 126 dpcm)
xxhdpi : 144x144px (480 dpi / 189 dpcm)
xxxhdpi : 192x192px (640 dpi / 252 dpcm)

dip : 48x48dip (dip = dp)

mm : 76 mm (depends on the real device dpi)
```

iPhone icon sizes (dpi is a bit different on iPads)

```
non-retina : 57x57px (163 dpi / 64 dpcm)
retina : 114x114px (326 dpi / 128 dpcm)

mm : 89 mm
```

Answer (score 7):

The Android icon guidelines say that the baseline should be assumed to be mdpi, so if you're using the default drawable directory, images should be designed according to those guidelines (48x48 for launcher icons). According to the documentation:

> The system assumes that default resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which is a normal screen size and a medium density. (from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

There's a bit of information there regarding when images from the default drawable directory are used too, but nothing specific.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following link will help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size5

According to Icon Design launcher:

> Launcher icon dimensions for
>   high-density (hdpi) screens:
>
> Full Asset: 72 x 72 px
>
> Icon: 60 x 60 px
>
> Square Icon: 56 x 56 px
>
> Launcher icon dimensions for
>   medium-density (mdpi) screens:
>
> Full Asset: 48 x 48 px
>
> Icon: 40 x 40 px
>
> Square Icon: 38 x 38 px
>
> Launcher icon dimensions for
>   low-density (ldpi) screens:
>
> Full Asset: 36 x 36 px
>
> Icon: 30 x 30 px
>
> Square Icon: 28 x 28 px

Comment: Ya. I know that. But what should be "default"?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html, the default launcher icon size should be 48 x 48 pixels.